# Weight Paint Disappears When I Select a Bone

Tags: weight-painting

I'm on Blender 2.81 and I'm having an issue selecting bones while weight-painting. My Armature has been parented to my Player mesh with Automatic Weights. I have `Edit`-->`Lock Object Modes` off. Also, I use Left-Click select mode. Here's what happens...

- In Object Mode, I select my Armature, then shift-select my Player mesh, then enter Weight Paint mode (see the first image). As you can see, the weights show up just fine, and my Armature has been automatically switched to Pose Mode. This is expected.
- Next, I try to Ctrl+Left-Click (this also happens when I Shift+Left-Click) a bone on my Armature. What I expect to happen is that the bone is selected **and the weights for that bone get highlighted**. However, this isn't what happens. Instead, the weights all disappear and everything goes gray. (See the second image.) It looks like I'm still indeed in Weight Paint mode, but I can't see any weights.

I appreciate any help!! :)

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

**UPDATE:** Just posted [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/weight-paint-disappears-when-i-select-a-bone/1196086/5) and replied [here](https://developer.blender.org/T71976). This is definitely a community-known bug. Also, I just confirmed selecting bones while in weight-paint mode works on a Windows computer with a better graphics card (and I’m assuming also the latest drivers).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to have all of the bones and the object selected together, just select the bone you want to weight paint in pose mode, and then select the object *Player* or the object you want to weight paint. You do not need to have both objects selected together to weight paint.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that didn't fix my issue.